# Stop Safari 6 JS Debugger From Being So Verbose

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari

I'm finding the Safari 6 debugger to be extremely verbose and pauses execution of JS for every minor exception. Does anyone know how to disable this?

Example:

- Open web inspector in Safari 6
- Visit http://www.google.com/mobile/

Notice how even if you were in the JS console, you'd be switched into debug view to see the error. This is not very good and slows debugging down considerably.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

to disable the the breaks, you have to go to "**Breakpoints** (CTRL + 7)" and then disable "**All Uncaught Exceptions**".
This should do the trick.

But i myself, find that the console is really slow, it has a delay until it shows the "console.log()" messages. This is quite annoying.

Comment: I couldn't event tell that little right-hand arrow was a button until just now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about the responsiveness of the console yet. This problem I was having made it so I couldn't even see the console until I saw each uncaught exception.

Comment: I'm seeing the delay you mentioned now and it is really annoying. Even if I type 1+1 into the console, I don't get the sum until 5-10 seconds later.